# Regular expression in javascript to delete left zero in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can create regular expression in javascript to delete  left zero in a string?

---

I have this:

"01/01/2015"

---

I need obtain this:

"1/1/2015"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a date, then Zan's approach is probably the better one.  But if you truly want to do it with regular expressions, then here's an approach:

To remove just the first leading zero:

```
"01/01/2015".replace(/^0(.*)/,"$1")
```

More verbose:

```
str = "01/01/2015"
pat = /^0(.*)/      // Match string beginning with ^, then a 0, then any characters.   
str.replace(pat,"$1")    // Replace with just the characters after the zero
```

---

To remove leading zeros in each grouping:

```
str = "01/01/2015"
pat = /(^|[/])0(\d*)/g  //  Match string begin ^ or /, then a 0, then digits. 'g' means globally. 
str.replace(pat,"$1$2")  // Replace with the part before and after the 0.
```

Comment: Nice with regex, but more verbose is not removing zero for month

Answer (score 2):

you can try without REGEX:

```
var myDate="01/01/2015";
var d = new Date(myDate);
alert(d.getDate() + '/' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getFullYear());
```

Answer (score 1):

hope this is what you want:

```
s = '01/01/2015'; // check  11/01/2015 、11/11/2015、01/10/2015 ...
s = s.replace(/0*(\d+)\/0*(\d+)\/(\d+)/,"$1/$2/$3");
alert(s);
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of why this would solve the OP's problem. Help others to understand.